# Get all the record with common words

Tags: prolog

I need to get all the record with common words. But it's too difficult for me.

```
record(id(1),myString([exchange, company, price]).
record(id(2),myString([share_current, change, industry, company]).
record(id(3),myString([currency, trans_share, type, and]).
record(id(4),myString([price_max, price_min, share_current, work]).
```

And result:

```
myString([exchange, company, price]
myString([share_current, change, industry, company]
myString([price_max, price_min, share_current, work]
```

Comment: Why not `id(3)`?

Comment: common word: company
Answer: myString([exchange, company, price]
myString([share_current, change, industry, company];
common word: share_current 
Answer: myString([share_current, change, industry, company]
myString([price_max, price_min, share_current, work]